How can i run tests of an shared folder?
I have 2 projects which have other folder in common, the thing is that i have components which are shared in both projects and they need unit tests, jasmine is reading tests from both projects but not from the shared folder.
I tried to include spec files from core project in tsconfig.spec of both projects but is not working, i tried to create the shared folder as a library with his own tsconfigs, but neither.
